# Get Sum & Average of each month using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below database table,In here i need group some data and get sum and avg of some data.

In here i need to calculate Item marketers monthly sales(Each Month)

As a Example :

I need to get a Patric Newton's Sales in Each months.

And also i need to calculate AvarageFactor of each month Each employee.

```
AvgFactor = SUM(Daily Sales)/ SUM(Value Factor) * 100( Each Month )
```

### Database Table

[image]

I have tried it like below,

```
SELECT ItemMarketerName,DailySales,ValueFactor,[Month],[Year]
FROM [SR_Hotel].[dbo].[Table_1]
WHERE ItemMarketerName IS NOT NULL
Group by ItemMarketerName,DailySales,ValueFactor,[Month],[Year]
Order by ItemMarketerName
```

Comment: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ - you should add tabular data in a format easier to read than an image.

Comment: What's your expect result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not include your aggregated columns in your `GROUP BY`.

Try:

```
SELECT ItemMarketerName, [Month], [Year], SUM(DailySales), SUM(DailySales) / SUM(ValueFactor) * 100
FROM [SR_Hotel].[dbo].[Table_1]
WHERE ItemMarketerName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ItemMarketerName, [Month], [Year]
ORDER BY ItemMarketerName
```